# How to sort individual word in an array of words in objective C?

Tags: objective-c

For example, if I have the array that contains words [cat dog tac god act]. How am I going to sort each individual word inside the array, so the new array should be [act dgo act dgo act] ? Thank you.

Comment: what kind of sorting is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fast way to find all anagrams inside an array in objective c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715026/what-is-the-fast-way-to-find-all-anagrams-inside-an-array-in-objective-c)

Comment: @Fogmeister: thanks for suggestion. IMO, it should not be duplicate to the my other question. More precisely, this is one part question of the whole problem that I posted earlier.

Comment: Uh, I guess you'd sort the letters.  And, for some strange reason, there's no already-defined NSString function to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic idea, and I leave the the implementation to you. Loop through the array, and for each of those strings:

1. split it into an array of letters;
2. sort the array of letters;
3. join letters back to a string